# How to use third-party SendGrid Email Validation API in Gravity Forms?

Tags: plugins, filters, api, plugin-gravity-forms, validation

Please let me know how to use SendGrid Email Validation API in Gravity Forms, using `gform_field_validation` filter?

**Gravity Forms filter example:**

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation', function ( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {

  if ( $field->get_input_type() === 'email' && $result['is_valid'] ) {

    // put your code here

  }

  return $result;

}, 10, 4 );
```

**SendGrid Email Validation API:**
https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/managing-contacts/email-address-validation/

**Gravity Forms `gform_field_validation` Filter:**
https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_field_validation/#11-email-validation-by-third-party-api

**I want this type of result:**

```
{
  "result": {
    "email": "john.doe@gmial.com",
    "verdict": "Invalid",
    "score": 0.00089,
    "local": "john.doe",
    "host": "gmial.com",
    "suggestion": "gmail.com",
    "checks": {
      "domain": {
        "has_valid_address_syntax": true,
        "has_mx_or_a_record": true,
        "is_suspected_disposable_address": false
      },
      "local_part": {
        "is_suspected_role_address": false
      },
      "additional": {
        "has_known_bounces": false,
        "has_suspected_bounces": true
      } 
    },
    "ip_address": "123.45.67.89"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to make a [wp_remote_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/) request to the validation endpoint. Probably relevant old question: [Sending JSON string through wp_remote_post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/313036/3276). You possibly also want to cache the results somewhere.

Comment: @Rup It's helped me a lot :)